# How to cascade two DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where I want to have two drop down lists. When a user selects an option from the first DDL, I'd like that value to determine what the second DDL has for options. Here is my code behind and markup:

```
Select a Category:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateDDLsections">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
Select an Organization:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName" 
    DataValueField="ID" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" >
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class AddRecord : System.Web.UI.Page
{


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void PopulateDDLsections(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  orgID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrg.SelectedValue.ToString());
    //}
    int orgID;

    // Make sure we parse the selected value to an int.
    if (Int32.TryParse(ddlOrg.SelectedValue.ToString(), out orgID))
    {
        // Form the select statement from the orgID we just parsed.
        String command = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [ORG_SECTIONS] WHERE OrgID = {0}", orgID);
        // Assign the SelectCommand.
        AccessDataSource2.SelectCommand = command;
    }
}
}
```

What this currently produces is nothing in the second DDL. Any ideas?

Comment: Int32.TryParse(ddlOrg.SelectedValue.ToString(), out orgID)  - replace ddlOrg with ddlCategory? ddlOrg does not have anything selected yet, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user **ControlParameter** of **AccessDataSource**.

**Note:** you do not need **OnSelectedIndexChanged** if you use ControlParameter.

For example,

```
Select a Category:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
    DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"></asp:AccessDataSource>

<br />
Select an Organization:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
    DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Name="ID" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824905/296861) with SqlDataSource.

Comment: Ding ding ding! You are the winner! Control Parameter is the game maker!

Answer (score -1):

Your If statement in codebehind is checking the wrong dropdown.

Change to your If to check ddlCategory, since it's what you need to determine the 2nd dropdown.