# How to bind data from dropdownlist to another in formview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlist in formview InsertItemTemplate, i want when i change selectedindex in dropdownlist A, dropdownlist B will change. 
I got an error when change selectedindex in dropdownlist A: **"Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."**

I'm stuck here for hour, anyone have idea.

Here my code in design:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblClass" runat="server" Text="Class:"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboClass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" DataSourceID="sdsClass" DataTextField="ClassName" DataValueField="ClassID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboClass_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="lblStudent" runat="server" Text="Student Name:"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboStudent" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("StudentID") %>' Width="100%" DataSourceID="sdsStudent" DataTextField="StudentName" DataValueField="StudentID"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And here my code behind:

```
protected void cboClass_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sdsStudent.SelectParameters["ClassID"].DefaultValue = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    (frmExamScore.FindControl("cboStudent") as DropDownList).DataBind();
}
```

Comment: DropDown List is not a `DataBound Control` so you can not use `Bind()` method on it. You can set `SelectedValue` property of dropdown list when you bind it to the datasource.

Comment: Do you have the way to handle it?

Comment: You need to set SelectedValue property of dropdown list when you bind it to the datasource. That's how you handle it. Can you share the code where you bind the `cboStudent` to a datasource. And how you are assigning value to `StudentID`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am inserting with InsertItemTemplate in formview, cboStudent is binding data with seleted value in cboClass, here my sqldatasoure for cboStudent:
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsStudent" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sConn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT StudentID, StudentName + ' - ' + CONVERT (nvarchar, DateOfBirth, 103) AS StudentName FROM Students WHERE (ClassID = @ClassID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: @tgolisch i do, i get error when i try change cboStudent data when change selected cboClass, if i not do this it work fine

Comment: What happens if you remove SelectedValue attribute from the cboStudent ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it work perfectly but when click button to insert, it does not receive value StudentID

Comment: You are trying to get the StudentID using `cboStudent.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824540/how-to-select-cascading-dropdownlist-with-sqldatasource Answer of this question simplifies what you want to achieve. You don't need to write selectedIndex change event if you follow this.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i follow this, but it just work if i remove SelectedValue='<%#Bind("StudentID") %>'  in cboStudent

Comment: But you are not getting the selected StudentID at the server side, right ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, i just want StudentID to insert from formview

Comment: removing `SelectedValue='<%#Bind("StudentID") %>' ` did resolve your issue? Did it introduce any other issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, it solve my problem but i get another issue, because i remove SelectedValue='<%#Bind("StudentID") %>' so i don't have StudentID when i click insert. Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentID'